# Question about a Symmetric relation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I have the following relation **R ⊆ N × N** and is defined as **R = {(x, y); 3 | (x − y)}**

A symmetric relation is defined as follows **∀x, y ∈ A : (xRy ⇒ yRx)**

What i did was, i defined **R = {(x, y); 3 | (x − y)}** as **x - y = 3k** and 
**y - x = -3k** to get **3 | (y - x)** in order to prove the implication **xRy ⇒ yRx**

I know this relation is symmetric i just dont understand the reason behind it, so any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is right. That is the the reason behind it. If $x,y \in \mathbb{N}$ and $xRy$, then there exists $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $x-y = 3k$ so $y-x = -3k$. Hence $yRx$.

Comment: What confuses me the most here is this part **y - x = -3k**  why negative 3? What would happen if it was **y - x = 3k** instead?

Comment: @newplayer $y-x=-(x-y)=-(3k)=-3k$

Comment: Multiply the equation $3k = x-y$ by $-1$. Then you get $y-x$ on the right hand side and $3 \cdot (-k)$ on the left hand side. The thing is that you need to change $k$. For example $3$ is a divisor of $9-6$ since $3 \cdot 1 = 9-6 = 3$. But $3$ is also a divisor of $6-9$! Here you can see that since $3 \cdot (-1) = 6-9 = -3$.

Answer (score 0):

What you did was basically correct. Let $(x,y) \in R$, i.e. we have that $3$ is a divisor of $x - y$, such that we can write $3k = x-y$ for a suitable $k$. Since $x - y = -(y - x)$ and $3 \mid x-y$ we also know that $3$ is a divisor of $y-x$, since $3 \cdot (-k) = y - x$.